# How to get meta data from a live streaming radio Service online?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, avfoundation, metadata

I am trying to get the metadata (artwork and song name) from a livestreaming audio URL.

1. http://page.streamerportal.com/play/ASX/44/play
2. http://page.streamerportal.com/play/PLS/44/play
3. http://page.streamerportal.com/play/AUDIO/44/play

I have tried looking around and found an accepted answer (On stack overflow) and tried it

```
 var Player: AVPlayer!
    var PlayerItem: AVPlayerItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://page.streamerportal.com/play/ASX/44/play")
        let playBackURL = URL(string: "http://page.streamerportal.com/play/ASX/44/play")
        PlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: playBackURL!)
        self.PlayerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        Player = AVPlayer(playerItem: PlayerItem)
        Player.play()
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath != "timedMetadata" { return }

        let data: AVPlayerItem = object as! AVPlayerItem

        for item in data.timedMetadata! {
            print(item.value!)
        }

    }
```

When i try this my function observeValue(.......) is never being called, can anyone please help me with this or provide a solution for how to retrieve meta data ?